# Naming numbers in American English

Tags: javascript, strings, converting, numbers-to-words

This seems like a popular topic lately, so I took a crack at it.

Related questions are [Number to Words](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58833/number-to-words) and [Converting a number to the text representation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/58884/converting-a-number-to-the-text-representation).

I used [this article](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/saying_large_numbers01.html) as a guideline. The article mostly explains by example, but some key points were:

- Use a hyphen to separate numbers like *twenty-two*.
- Using *and* is not a requirement, so 2014 can be written as *two thousand fourteen*.
- No use of commas is mentioned, other than as placeholders in numbers represented with numerals.

It mentions that numbers *may* be spoken like *two thousand **and** fourteen* in the last footnote; maybe this could be an optional feature added later. If someone finds a better reference showing that any of this is incorrect, please let me know.

```
(function (global) {
    'use strict';

    var scalePrefix = ['m', 'b', 'tr', 'quadr', 'quint', 
            'sext', 'sept', 'oct', 'non', 'dec'];

    var digits = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
            'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];

    var tens = ['', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty',
            'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

    var teens = { 0: 'ten', 1: 'eleven', 2: 'twelve', 
            3: 'thir', 5: 'fif', 8: 'eigh' };

    function nameDigit(digit) {
        return digits[digit];
    }

    function nameTenToNineteen(number) {
        var prefix = teens[number] || digits[number];

        return number < 3 ? prefix : prefix + 'teen';
    }

    function nameTripletScale(digitCount) {
        return  digitCount < 3 ? '' :
                digitCount < 6 ? 'thousand' :
                scalePrefix[digitCount / 3 - 2] + 'illion';
    }

    function nameTripletHead(number) {
        return +number ? (nameDigit(number) + ' hundred') : '';
    }

    function nameTripletTail(digitPair) {
        var separator = +digitPair[1] ? '-' : '';

        return  digitPair[0] == 0 ? nameDigit(digitPair[1]) :
                digitPair[0] == 1 ? nameTenToNineteen(digitPair[1]) :
                tens[digitPair[0]] + separator + digits[digitPair[1]];
    }

    function extractSymbols(number) {
        var symbols, digitCount;

        number = ('' + number);
        if (!number.match(/^(-?)[\d,]+/)) {
            throw new Error('invalid number: ' + number);
        }
        symbols = number.replace(/,/g, '').split('');
        digitCount = symbols.length - (symbols[0] == '-');
        if (digitCount / 3 > scalePrefix.length + 2) {
            throw new Error('number out of range: ' + number);
        }

        return symbols;
    }

    function nameNumber(number) {
        var symbols = extractSymbols(number),
            sign = '',
            segments = [],
            segment;

        function append(item) {
            item && segments.push(item);
        }

        if (symbols[0] == '-') {
            sign = 'negative ';
            symbols.shift();
        }

        while (symbols.length % 3) {
            symbols.unshift(0);
        }

        while (symbols.length) {
            segment = symbols.splice(0, 3);
            append(nameTripletHead(segment[0]));
            append(nameTripletTail(segment.slice(1)));
            if (segment.join('') > 0) {
                append(nameTripletScale(symbols.length));
            }
        }

        return sign + (segments.join(' ') || 'zero');
    }

    global['nameNumber'] = nameNumber;

}(this));
```

- I am especially interested in feedback on better names for things, especially things like `teens` which are not quite accurate. I'm also looking for feedback on any bugs or mistakes. The internal `nameNumber` also looks a little bit too busy, maybe it should be broken up more but I wasn't really happy with anything I tried so far.
- I am especially uninterested in hearing about unreadable/unmaintainable ternary conditionals. They look fine to me. If you can suggest a different way to write it that's still readable and doesn't double the number of relevant LOC, though, I might be interested after all.

Test it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C8n9a/2/); there's a test harness and a passing test case for each example from the linked article.

Comment: Minor bug: `nameTripletTail` doesn't account for a trailing zero so `nameNumber("20")` returns `"twenty-"`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness good catch, I actually found that article and added that hyphen at the last minute. Should be an easy fix (and fixed, I think).

Comment: While I don't have a reference, I do recall that you should never insert "and" into the number. It's a common habit for people when speaking once the number goes over one hundred because it feels like a list once there are enough terms.

Comment: [Rules for Writing Numbers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.grammarbook.com%2Fnumbers%2Fnumbers.asp&ei=oI7eU6qXO4L_oQTQi4DACA&usg=AFQjCNH9V2AiIiKlFDOlfHfPkhCzH4dR-w&sig2=pKXrUpfvlerCzWLbmnSxHg) ([cached](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Hj-5dkzZQBAJ:www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) summarizes the rules from a few good media sources, including one for using "and" with fractions.

Comment: No reference, but I was taught in school to only write "and" to stand for the decimal point. Ex: 112.56 = One hundred twelve and 56 hundredths.

Comment: You should be able to group digits with spaces instead of commas, like `"20 000"`. Also, maybe validate against having shenanigans like `"1,,1" => "eleven"`?

Answer (score 7):

Interesting question, impressive code.

I only found one thing that could be considered a bug:
`nameNumber('15.000')` will return *"one hundred fiftyundefined thousand"*, this could be fixed by changing your regex to

```
if (!number.match(/^(-?)[\d,]+$/)) {
    throw new Error('invalid number: ' + number);
}
```

Other than that I think you went a little overboard in some places to achieve the ultimate DRYness.

This:

```
var digits = ['', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
var tens = ['', 'ten', 'twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
var teens = { 0: 'ten', 1: 'eleven', 2: 'twelve', 3: 'thirteen', 5: 'fifteen', 8: 'eighteen' };

function nameDigit(digit) {
    return digits[digit];
}

function nameTenToNineteen(number) {
    return teens[number] || digits[number] + 'teen';
}
```

(ignore the removed newlines) puts the `'teen'` back in the `teens` array, you no longer need a temporary variable or encode that you do not have the add `'teen'` for 10,11 and 12. This has less characters, and less complexity.

The same ( though I am not sure this would reduce character count here ) can be said for `scalePrefix`, it took me a while to figure that this was supposed to return `m`illlion, `b`illion etc. If you were to add `''`, `'thousand'` and `'illion'` at the end of existing entries, then your `nameTripletScale` could be

```
function nameTripletScale(digitCount) {
    return scalePrefix[digitCount / 3 ];
}
```

Note how it sneakily removes an offensive ternary :P It would also no longer require the magical `+2` in `if (digitCount / 3 > scalePrefix.length + 2) {`

In `extractSymbols` you mix parsing, conversion, validation and error handling, I usually don't like that but the code is succinct enough that I can not offer a reasonable alternative.

The same goes for `function append(item) {` in `nameNumber`, it looks a bit busy but removing it looks worse.

One last item is `nameDigit(digit)`, it requires more characters than say `digits[digit]` and about half of the time you actually use direct array access instead of calling `nameDigit`, I would just drop `nameDigit` entirely.

Comment: The regex thing I actually noticed and corrected in my copy, but it was such a small change I decided not to bump the question. I didn't think anyone would catch it, though... good eye :)

Comment: I think you're right about adding "teen" to the teens. I'm not sure how I feel about adding "illion" to the, ah, illions. If you wanted to add undecillion, duodecillion and so on, each addition would add twice as many characters and another repeated "illion." Not sure whether this is going overboard but I was having trouble stomaching all that repetition when I wrote this.

Comment: Agreed on illions, it's a matter of taste